# Delphi 10.2 разное расположение компонента во время проектирования и выполнения программы

Tags: delphi, проектирование, компоненты

Доброе время суток,
Такая проблема на *TGroupBox* расположены 2 *TSpeedButton*.
Во времая проектирования верхняя кнопка расположена нормально, т.е. в рамках *TGroupBox* (см. рис1).
А во время, выполнения, она съезжает с *TGroupBox* (см. рис2). Программно я это не делаю.
Тем более, проверяю свойство «Top» кнопки и при проектировании и при выполнении, оно = 3.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как привести приложение во время выполнения к нормальному виду?
P.S.
Тем более как может кнопка НАезжать на рамки *TGroupBox*, если она находится в контейнере.

Comment: добавьте еще один групбокс, и киньте туда кнопки. если поведение будет таким же, то хороший вопрос. если будет нормально, то сравните настройки в обоих случаях.

Comment: новый groupbox, новые speedbutton, ситуация такая же. Хотя до этого все было норм., но кнопки располагались не по вертикали, а по горизонтали

Answer (score 0):

У вас кнопка никуда не уезжает, у вас при разработке программы включены темы оформления, а в самой программе они отключены, из-за этого по-разному выглядят как сама кнопка, так и GroupBox:

[image: что_происходит]

Comment: Я не менял тему оформления, откуда? Тему не отключал, я даже не знаю как это делается

Comment: И это не кнопка съезжает, а *TGroupBox*

Comment: Вы не меняли, но в самой Delphi они включены - поэтому всё что на форме по-умолчанию рисуется с темой. А в приложении вы их не включали, поэтому рисуется без темы. И групбокс не съезжает - у него просто по-другому рисуется рамка (появляются поля вокруг неё).

Comment: так, посмотрите пожалуйста, вот те же компоненты, но размещены по другому https://www.dropbox.com/s/ra2kculwvehy37f/DeviceNC.bmp?dl=0 и все нормально отображается... и в настройках * "Projects -> Options -> Applications", там Manifest File -> "Auto Generate", Enable Runtime Themes -> [галки не было]*

Comment: вот если можете то гляньте старый dfm в котором все нормально https://www.dropbox.com/s/cyf9mfhy2b5a35y/UDeviceNC%20old.dfm?dl=0 , а вот уже новый dfm https://www.dropbox.com/s/ieavbfz8m9lpqc8/UDeviceNC.dfm?dl=0 в котором group съехал

Comment: мне вот интересно, на форме есть другой *SpeedButton* "*sbReceiveCostUnit*", он находится в *GroupBox* "*grbEditNC*", но он почему-то не съезжает во время выполнения

Comment: Еще интересно, как может "Object inspector" при проектировании показывать высоту groupbox = 55, и при выполнении программы лона = 55, а если сравнить с посщью printscreen, высоты - разные 
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftmt3n7d7aq2oov/5.png?dl=0

Comment: 1. Положите эти два групбокса на форму, поставьте им `ParentColor := False`, а самой форме задайте какой-нибудь чёрный цвет - тогда вы увидите какого размера оба груп-бокса на самом деле.

Comment: 2. Если вам не нужен заголовок групбокса - зачем вы его используете, если для этого есть TPanel?

Comment: Спасибо...
Действительно останавлюсь на TPanel.

Только странно, столько уже с TGroupBox, работал (кидал его на форму проектировал), а с таким явным "перемещением" первый раз столкнулся.

P.S.
А может уже и сталкивался - не помню...